# what is the most accurate type for this variable?

Tags: html, vba, variable-names

here is a part of my code. I managed to get the result I wanted to but only by declaring Elements as a as Variant since it didn't work as a HTMLElementCollection. Can someone explain me why ? And what's the most accurate variable then ? Thanks

```
' Find + Click on the login Button
' We filter the elements which have the tagename <input> since as we can see in the code that the login element is on of them
    Set Elements = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each element In Elements

        If (element.getAttribute("value") = "Login") Then ' we go through each elements with the tagname input and if the value term
            element.Click                                  ' is called "Login" then we click on that element
            Exit For
        End If

     Next element
```

Comment: You need to add the reference to ms internet controls. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219327(v=office.11).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx

Comment: What do you get from `Debug.Print TypeName(Elements)` ?

Comment: I have never used this command, what it it supposed to do ?